# How can I change the hashtag names in anythingslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, anythingslider

I am using anythingslider and if you are familiar with it, you might then know that it has the following function:

```
hashTags : true,      // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
```

Which you can use to make it generate unique URLs for each slide as if they were pages. But the downside is that it generates generic names for the hashtag. (e.g.

`http://www.mysite.com/#&panel1-2`

My question is, how can you change the names of those hashtags to custom names for each slide?

Right now I am using the following function to make it display each slide title in the navigation bar:

```
navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){
    return panel.find('h6').text();
}
```

And all I do is that I add the title in a `<h6>` element. So, how could I use these titles to also rename the hashtags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the default hash and use the `onSlideComplete` callback to update the window hash ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VM8XG/4488/); and [full screen demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Mottie/VM8XG/4488/show/#rawr)):

*note: the h6 also has an id (no spaces allowed) vs the text of the h6 (spaces allowed, and used in the navigation tabs)

HTML

```
<ul id="slider">   
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/200" alt="" />
        <h6 id="meow">Meow</h6>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="" />
        <h6 id="grey">Grey</h6>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placebear.com/320/200" alt="" />
        <h6 id="rawr">Rawr</h6>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320x200/000/fff.jpg" alt="" />
        <h6 id="bnw">Black & White</h6>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placedog.com/320/200" alt="" />
        <h6 id="woof">Woof</h6>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Script

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
    hashTags: false,

    // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    navigationFormatter: function(index, panel) {
        return panel.find('h6').text();
    },

    // Callback when the plugin finished initializing
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
        slider.$items.find('h6').each(function(){
            // add some prefix to the id so setting the hash doesn't
            // make the page jump
            this.id = "tmp_" + this.id;
        });
    },

    // Callback when slide completes - no event variable!
    onSlideComplete: function(slider) {
        var hash = '#' + slider.$currentPage.find('h6')[0].id.replace(/tmp_/,'');
        // remove prefix so hash works on page load
        window.location.hash = hash;
    }

});
```

And here's [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/rWjrU/673/) using the panel ID's instead of the h6 ID's.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! Thank you very much. The only downside is that it scrolls down the page to focus the #id`` that it's being processed. (You can see that in my WIP site: http://anekdamian.com/Insurance/ ).

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that... I updated the demo to add a prefix to the ID's so the page won't jump.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I tried it, but it's still jumping. Isn' there a way to display it just as a word and not as a hashtag?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you missed the extra code I added in the `onInitialized` function. Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used anythingslider but if you want to change it's hashtags, you could start looking for `window.location.hash` in the script to begin as the hash generating part would start there.